Large vector families with certain spanning properties on percolation
I'm interested in large families of vectors, which include many large linearly-independent sets, with the property that percolation results in any individual vector in the family not being spanned with non-negligible probability. More precisely,  does there exist some finite field $\mathbb{F}$ such that for arbitrarily large dimension $d$ and integer $k=k(d) = \omega(1)$ (e.g. $k=\log d$ or $k=\log \log d$ will do), there is a family of vectors $B \subseteq \mathbb{F}^d$ such that:

$B$ is the disjoint union of $B_1,\ldots,B_k$, where each $B_i$ is an independent set of size on the order of $d$ (for example, $|B_i| \geq d/2$).
If $S$ is a uniformly random subset of $B$ (i.e., it includes each element of $B$ independently with probability $1/2$), then any $e \in B$ is not spanned by $S$ with probability at least on the order of $1/k$. Formally, the following should hold for each $e \in B$: $$\Pr [ e \not\in span(S)] \geq \Omega\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

This is a question that seems vaguely related to error correcting codes, as well as to constructions of vector families with certain girth properties. I was able to prove that anything substantially larger than $1/k$ is impossible, but I can't seem rule out a construction which attains something on the order of $1/k$. Any pointers to related constructions appreciated.

Can you be more precise about your quantifiers? For example, "for all $\mathbb{F}$". Also, you need $k\frac{d}{2} \le |\mathbb{F}^d|$. Why not just be precise? idgi

You are right. Hopefully this is more clear.

Thanks, but it's still vague. You should say "for SOME arbitrarily large ...", since "such that for arbitrarily large ..." means "such that for ALL arbitrarily large ...", which you don't want, since you need $k$ to be small (but you're asking if there is some $k = k(d)$ that is $\omega(1)$).
